# Formula field to evaluate two fields separately and returns a value based on one or the other values

Tags: formula, case, picklist, if

The formulas work separately but I need the formula to evaluate the formulas in a "or" situation.  IF I use & for the first formula - it concatenates the field but I want a Closed Or an Open value.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Shipped__c , "C"), "Closed", "Open")    
OR
IF( Outstanding_Quantity__c  <= 0, "Closed", "Open")
```

Or this 2nd formula would also accomplish my goal -

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Shipped__c , "C"),
CASE( zzItemCategory__c ,
"ZBIL", "Closed",
"ZRTN", "Closed",
"Open" )
, "Open")
```

The issue with the second formula is that it only evaluates the Case section and not the pickval portion of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Things like `&`, `&&`, `||`, `AND()`, and `OR()` have specific meanings in formulas. Formulas in Salesforce *means you actually are writing some code* (albeit a more limited version of "coding" compared to writing "actual code" in a language like Apex).

So while you don't need hours upon hours of learning like you do with "actual code", you do still need to think like a computer.

`&` or `+` concatenates strings together
`&&` and `AND()` are both the Boolean "And" function (i.e. if everything being AND-ed together is true, then the result is true)
`||` and `OR()` are both the Boolean "Or" function (if *any* of the things being OR-ed together is true, then the result is true)

For simple `IF()` statements like this, writing down what you want to do in plain language (English, German, Afrikaans, whatever) first can be helpful because *your formula should end up reading similar to plain language*.

That is, you are trying to say

```
if field x has this value, or field y has that value, then output1, else, output2
```

rather than

```
if field x has this value, then output1, else output2
if field y has that value, then output1, else output2
```

Put more plainly, *your two fields should be part of the same `IF()` statement*

```
IF(
    OR(
        /* field X has this value or */
        ISPICKVAL(Shipped__c , "C"),
        /* field Y has that value */
        Outstanding_Quantity__c  <= 0
    ),
    /* then output */
    "Closed",
    /* else output (when Shipped is not C and outstanding qty > 0) */
    "Open"
)
```